# Getting an error while running an odoo-bin in odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo, python-babel

Getting an error as ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.dates'; 'babel' is not a package while running an odoo-bin
I have clone odoo 15.0 repostiorary

i have tried to run requirement file and tries to install babel

Comment: Basically what you need is to create a virtual environment, to activate it and to install the requirements.txt in it. If you did so, try to run `pip list | grep babel` to see if it's installed

Answer (score 0):

1. set up locally a virtual environment in the directory containing the odoo source:

- https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-odoo-ubuntu
- https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/tutorials/getting_started/02_setup.html

2. activate it using this bash command:

```bash
    source /bin/activate
```

3. in the same bash window, install the missing package

```bash
    sudo pip3 install babel
```